# I uploaded my wordpress site to the web and pages link to localhost

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When i uploaded my WordPress site to the web. I clicked a page from the menu and it redirect to localhost.

And i uploaded my hole new site to the web and my theme does not change?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Search & replace for db and then activate your theme in 'wp-admin > appearance > themes'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run a search/replace on your database to replace the local domain with the live domain. Until you do that, all links on the live domain will redirect to the local domain.

This is a tool that can do that: 
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

To use this, unzip and upload the directory to your web hosting root, and then visit newdomain.com/your-directory-name/index.php in a browser.

- Back up your database before running this.
- **Delete this folder after you are finished** as it is a major security issue if left there.
- More detailed instructions are on that   page.

More information on migrating a WP installation can be found in the codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

I don't understand your question about the theme. You'll need to provide more details on that.